# How to transform a column field into a list

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm trying to make a simple field calculation with ArcGIS 9.3:

```
New field = Old field - Old field(first value)
```

which in Calculate Field with python code should be

Expression: `!Old field! - first`

Code Block: `list= [AngOriz] first = list[0]`

The error is

```
ERROR 000539: Runtime error : name 'AngOriz' is not defined Failed to execute (Calculate Field).
```

How could I tranform a column field into a list?

---

I've tried this way

Expression:

```
makeCalc( !AngOriz!, !AngOriz!)
```

Code Block:

```
def makeCalc(x, y):
    first_value = y.split(' , ')[0] 
    return x-first_value
```

but still I get:

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: makeCalc( 43.01841, 43.01841) : 'float' object has no attribute 'split' Failed to execute (Calculate Field).

I need to calculate the difference between a value of a column and the first value of the same column (values are floating points).
The purpose is to calculate the displacement of different survey points on a landslide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the whole picture, what do you mean by Old field(first value)?? is Old field a text field with multiple values on it separated by commas or something like that? and if so, how come you use Old field before that?

But anyway, the error you're getting is because on the code block you haven't defined AngOriz... the best way to do what you're trying to do is inside a function, which gets the necessary values to work with as parameters, and returns the value to the field, here is an example:

on the Expression field:

```
my_function(!Old field!, !some_other_field!)
```

and on the codeblock:

```
def my_function(old_field, other_field):
    # supposing other_field is a list of int-values in a string = "1, 23, 5"
    first_value = int(other_field.split(', ')[0])
    return old_field - first_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long to answer. Had a busy week :-) Ok, I thought you meant a string field, not a float field, so forget about the split-stuff. I'm leaving the answer above, as it may help someone else looking for how to transform a (string) field into a list and use its values for a field calculation.

If I'm getting this right now, you mean the value of the first row of column AngOriz, right? So if this value doesn't change, then just use it "hard coded" on the function like this:

on the Expression field:

```
my_function(!AngOriz!)
```

and on the codeblock:

```
def my_function(old_field):        
    return old_field - 34.123  # just type the value of the first row here
```

If you don't want to "hard code" the value of the first row, then you would have to retrieve it somehow, but I'm not sure how you could do this on the field calculator. Probably you would have to solve this in a completely different way. With a script in arcpy or so.

Update: 
There is also the possibility of using global variables inside the field calculator - this means variables that are persistent between function calls. Because the function gets called by the field calculator for each row, and normally all variables inside a function "die" between calls, it is impossible to "remember" something on local variables. But you could use a global variable to save the first row's value and use it on the other following calls. I haven't tried it, but maybe something like this would work:

```
firstValue = None
def my_function(old_field):
    global firstValue
    if firstValue == None:  # this will be true only if this is the first call/row ...
        firstValue = old_field  # ... save the value on the global variable
    return old_field - firstValue
```